# JPA 2 + Weblogic 10.3.5 + TopLink Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am now struggling to configure my web project with (JPA2 + TopLink + WebLogic10.3.5).

Could you please indicate a way to me to solve my problem? 
(If it's possible to you give me a complete explanation, specially configuring the pesistence.xml file).

Comment: You should probably tell us what is not working, what you tried and give us the error messages. However you should probably search for a tutorial first.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with Weblogic 10.3.5 + JPA2 + EclipseLink.

- Follow the pre-classpath suggestions here: http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/deploying_jpa2_0_based_applications

[These jars should be under your module folder for weblogic]

- Add true to your weblogic.xml